# Server is unable to make outgoing ftp requests. How to open this?

Tags: security, iptables, firewall

I have setup a new server on rackspace & have used these exact rules in iptables http://articles.slicehost.com/assets/2007/9/4/iptables.txt

I don't want server to act as a ftp server but when I am trying to install any package say
`sudo apt-get install ruby`, I get the following errors

```
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main libruby1.8 amd64 1.8.7.302-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2610:148:1f10:3::89 80]
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main ruby1.8 amd64 1.8.7.302-2
  404  Not Found [IP: 2610:148:1f10:3::89 80]
Failed to fetch http:// ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/ruby1.8/libruby1.8_1.8.7.302-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2610:148:1f10:3::89 80]
Failed to fetch http:// ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/ruby1.8/ruby1.8_1.8.7.302-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 2610:148:1f10:3::89 80]
```

Comment: These are all 404 error messages. What is this whitespace in the errormessage anyway (not sure if it's related?) `http://_ _ftp.us.debian.org/debian/`

Comment: I had to add whitespace to post this question as it was not allowing more than 2 urls.

Comment: OK, these are all 404 - file not found - errormessages. Did you tune your `sources.list` in Debian correctly?

Comment: @AlexanderJanssen Nope I did not, any leads on how to configure the sources list? Also the iptable rules are good to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with FTP. The packages you requested simply aren't on the repository server. A common 404 error.

Make sure you run `apt-get update` before attempting to install anything.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. Sorry am new to linux so not really aware of these gotchas.